# Increase MacBook auto brightness

Tags: terminal, display, screen, auto-brightness

I like the MacBook's auto-brightness feature so I don't want to turn it off entirely but it's often a bit too dark for my liking. Is there a way to keep auto-brightness enabled but bump up the brightness it would normally pick in a given lighting condition? Maybe with terminal commands as it doesn't seem possible in settings UI.

[image: Mac Displays Settings UI]